# Create a record on DirPartyTable from code?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, sequences

I have to create a new record on `DirPartyTable` . 
I used this code:

```
DirPartyTable _myDirPartyTable;
myPartyNumber = DirPartyTable::getNewPartyNumber((webSession() == null));
myDirPartyTable = DirPartyTable::createNew(myPartyType , myName, myPartyNumber);
```

// or without partynumber

```
myDirPartyTable = DirPartyTable::createNew(myPartyType , myName);
```

But in both cases the *standard* method generate two *Sequence* ParyNumber.
In Debu mode I saw the system get two times the PartyNumber .

How can I create a record without creating holes in the sequence numeric?

I tried to use this another code:

```
select forupdate myDirPartyTable;
myDirPartyTable.name = ....;
//etc
myDirPartyTable.insert();
```

But does not create the record.

Thanks,
enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DirPartytable is the basis table of address book framework and is the top level of table inheritance hierarchy see references in [Implementing the Global Address Book Framework (White paper)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272867.aspx)

You shouldn't try to directly create a party but create from your entity which implement the DirParty framework. When you create a vendor, you don't create a DirParty (with herited tables) and then create a VendTable and link them all together. Creating a vendor will do it directly.

Then, if you still encounter two times Party number calls, log a case at Microsoft support.

ulisses: I solved problem, I have to create before the PartyType (Organization or Person etc...)and after update my created DirPartyTable.

Answer (score 0):

Just try the [AxDirPartyTable Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axdirpartytable.aspx) like:

```
AxDirPartyTable       axDirPartyTable;

axDirPartyTable = AxDirPartyTable::construct();
axDirPartyTable.parmName(myName);
axDirPartyTable.parmPartyNumber(myPartyNumber);
axDirPartyTable.save();
```

Examples could be found here: [How to create a record in Global address book throgh code](http://www.schweda.net/blog_ax.php?bid=515&wdl=en).